# C# Apply focused properties to FlowLayoutPanel like button behavior

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to apply focus behavior, similar to button blue border to FlowLayoutPanel. I tried to use GotFocus and LostFocus, but clearly that's not the way to go.

```
private void FlowLayoutPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Control).BackColor = SystemColors.GradientActiveCaption;
    //More operations.
}

private void Panel_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Control).BackColor = default(Color);
    //More operations.
}
```

While clicking on the FlowLayoutPanel nothing happens and while using tab the two event are invoked one after another.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a selectable control by default. You can create a custom flow layout panel by deriving from `FlowLayoutPanel` and set `Selectable` and `UserMouse` [control styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it selectable by mouse. Also to accept tab stop, set `TabStop` property to true:

```
class ExFlowLayoutPanel:FlowLayoutPanel
{
    public ExFlowLayoutPanel():base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
        TabStop = true;
    }
}
```

Then you can handle [`GotFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`LostFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Leave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei, It seems to enable me to set Enter event but leave still wont file.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi AmitLipman. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: I tested Enter and Leave and GotFocus and LostFocus and all of them worked properly. Probably to raise leave event you are clicking on form area. Click on another selectable control and the Leave and LostFocus events will raise.

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei many thanks. About the solution, the leave event fires only if I use tab, when I click other controls the leave event doesn't fire.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I double checked it. It works using mouse or using tab. Make sure to raise leave event you are clicking on a selectable control :)

Answer (score 2):

The only point of using a FLP is to get it to arrange child controls.  It is always a child control that gets the focus, not the FLP.  So sure, nothing happens.  You'd have to subscribe the Enter events of all the child controls to see the focus entering the panel or one of its children.  Leave is much harder to get right, that's going to flicker like a cheap motel.

Very ugly solution, you don't want to it that way.  Use the Application.Idle event instead, the best alternative when getting a reliable event just isn't practical.  Check the Parent of this.ActiveControl, like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Idle += CheckFlpFocus;
        this.Disposed += delegate { Application.Idle -= CheckFlpFocus; };
    }

    private bool FlpHasFocus;

    private void CheckFlpFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bool hasFocus = false;
        for (var ctl = this.ActiveControl; ctl != null; ctl = ctl.Parent) {
            if (ctl == flowLayoutPanel1) hasFocus = true;
        }
       if (hasFocus != FlpHasFocus) {
            FlpHasFocus = hasFocus;
            flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = hasFocus ? Color.Black : Color.White;
        } 
    }
```